# Method of transformation for a distribution

Tags: statistics

Let X $\sim U(0,1)$

(i) Derive the distribution of the random variables $W_1=X^2$ and $W_2=\sqrt{X}$

$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & 0<x<1 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

$\frac{\partial W_1}{\partial X}=2X$; $\frac{\partial W_2}{\partial X}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{X}}$

These are the only lines I know. The Jacobian has to come in place, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Where is the bivariate distribution ? I see two separate transformed variables only.

Comment: I got it in a set of examples, and it is the 1st time I am working with such types. Please excuse me for any wrong information delivered.

Comment: Which result do you know you have to apply to solve these exercises? Please be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to calculate the distribution of $W_1$

*1. Directly*

For $0<w_1<1$

$P(W_1<w_1)=P(X^2<w_1)=P(X<\sqrt{ w_1})=\sqrt{ w_1}$

$$F_{W_1}(w_1)=\begin{cases} 0, \quad \ \ \ \text{if} \  w_1<0 \\ \sqrt{ w_1},  \ \text{if} \  0\leq w_1\leq 1\\1, \ \ \ \text{if} \  w_1>0 \end{cases}$$

The pdf can be calculated straightforward.

*2. Using the transformation formula*

$$f_{W_1}(w_1)=\left|\frac{dg^{-1}(w_1)}{dw_1} \right|\cdot f_X(g^{-1}(w_1))$$

$g(x)=x^2$,  $g(x)$ has to be monotone.

$W_1=X^2\Rightarrow X=\sqrt{W_1}$

$g^{-1}(w_1)=\sqrt{w_1}$

$\left|\frac{dg^{-1}(w_1)}{dw_1} \right|=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w_1}}$

$f_X(g^{-1}(w_1))=1$